# How to map the pixel location of a marker on Google Map to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add an ability to drag and drop two markers to a google map, get their longitude and latitude and send it to the backend server.The initial position for those markers must be in a fixed points, to illustrate this imagine the following box as the div that contains the google map

```
 +++++++++++++++++++++
|                     |
|                  X  |
|                     |
|                     |
|                  Y  |
 +++++++++++++++++++++
```

The `X` and `Y` represent the initial locations of the two markers. The problems that I am facing are:

1. I cannot set the markers according to the `div` that contains them. The markers must be located according to longitude and latitude.
2. If I want to add my own markers to the google map using CSS, then the problem is that I cannot fetch the longitude and latitude for the located markers.

How to set the markers in a fixed positions according to the div itself, not to the longitude and latitude of the earth? Is there a way to map the pixel locations of a google map to longitude and latitude?

Comment: do you want to add markers on click or you know latlng of markers ?

Comment: @Akshaypadwal I want the marker to be in specific location at the beginning (as shown above) so that the user can drag the marker on a touch device, finally, I want to save the lat. and log. of the location that marker was located on.

Comment: at beginning you must be having latlng of marker right?

Comment: @Akshaypadwal no, the user will set the latlng of the marker. At the beginning the marker will be placed according to the div (see the image above) and I don't care about the latlng of the marker at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this transformation you will have to calculate the bounds of your div and the displayed area on the map in their own coordinate reference systems. Then you can transform your x/y coordinates this way:

```js
// Get the div's bounds
var divMap = document.getElementById('map');
var height = divMap.offsetHeight;
var width = divMap.offsetWidth;

// Get the map's bounds
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

// Latitude-pixel ratio
var ratioLat = (ne.lat() - sw.lat()) / height;

// Longitude-pixel ratio
var ratioLng = (ne.lng() - sw.lng()) / width;

// Transform the x/y coordinates to lat/lng coordinates
// Assuming that you already have the relative x and y coordinates in your div
var transLat = y * ratioLat + sw.lat();
var transLng = x * ratioLng + sw.lng();
//OR you can do this
var transLat = ne.lat() - y * ratioLat;
var transLng = ne.lng() - x * ratioLng;
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, I think that will complete the answer